# Requests. Сервер отвечает не тем html кодом, который мне нужен

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Я хотел получить HTML код страницы, но при при отправке запросов через **requests**, я получаю не то, что я бы получил, если бы открыл инструменты разработчика на странице через браузер.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.75'
}

link = 'https://discord.gift/testgift'

res = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Вот то, что я получаю:

[image: Результат]

Вот, что должно было быть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже пытался поставить User-Agent, прокси, но ничего не помогает. Сервер все равно видимо как-то распознает, что это не пользователь браузера.

Comment: Помимо того, что ответ может зависеть от User-Agent и печенек, в браузере страница модифицируется скриптами, которые сами могут вытягивать данные (обычно JSON) и добавлять их на страницу, так что искать нужные данные следует во всех запросах при загрузке страницы.

Comment: @viilpe, да, спасибо! Оказывается HTML код загружался JS скриптами.

Comment: Можно звгружать URL в selenium а потом драть от-туда загруженный html

Comment: @FotonPC Да, можно, но это слишком медленно.